# Azure Databricks - Generate SQL Select Statement with Columns

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have tables in Azure Databricks that I am using SQL to interact with via a notebook. I need to select all columns from a table with 200 columns, I need to select all of them but I need to modify some for a select insert (To modify specific columns for a PK). Therefore I can not use a select *. (There are multiple scenarios this is just my current objective)

How can I generate a select statement on a table with all the column names in a sql statement. This would be equivalent of a 'Select top N' in SSMS where it generates a select for the table I can than edit.

I have seen functions like describe and show but they can't build a select statement.
I am new to Databricks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or you need it automated?

Comment: I would use this all the time. I use this ability in SSMS multiple times a day.

Comment: how do you want to use it? Run some function that will print SQL for you?

Comment: That would be my thought. Some function/script that would dynamically build the select statement. I am new to Databricks and their 'database' structure. I am not sure if there are metadata views I could query in sql. I am not overly familiar with python.

Comment: If it helps. There is a 'Show Create Table' option for databricks sql.  I would be looking for some type of 'Show select table' or something. Not my question but an 'Show Update Table' would also be great. Perhaps I need to feature request this from them.
https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  It is really tough to make and modify SELECT statement for this kind of tables.  I have tried many ways and found using the 3rd party software to connect to the table on Azure Databricks worked fine.

**Here is what I do:**

1. Download the 3rd party software such as DBeaver
2. Download Databricks JDBC driver form this [page](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download).
3. Configure Databricks driver. Luckily there is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/dbeaver) for DBeaver.
4. Connect to the Databricks and find the table to generate SELECT statement.
5. Use DBeaver built-in function to generate it. See the screenshot below.

That's it!

I found this setup took just 10-15 minutes to complete saving much time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generate a SELECT statement from an existing table:

```py
def generate_select(schema_name, table_name):
    df = spark.sql(f'show columns in {schema_name}.{table_name}').collect()
    print('SELECT')
    print('  ' + ',\n  '.join([row[0] for row in df]))
    print(f'FROM {schema_name}.{table_name}')

generate_select('tpcds001tb', 'customer')
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT
  c_customer_sk,
  c_customer_id,
  c_current_cdemo_sk,
  c_current_hdemo_sk,
  c_current_addr_sk,
  c_first_shipto_date_sk,
  c_first_sales_date_sk,
  c_salutation,
  c_first_name,
  c_last_name,
  c_preferred_cust_flag,
  c_birth_day,
  c_birth_month,
  c_birth_year,
  c_birth_country,
  c_login,
  c_email_address,
  c_last_review_date
FROM tpcds001tb.customer
```