# Azure Data Bricks and DDL

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

Is there a way of generating an insert statement to use in another Azure Data Bricks workspace from a table like sql server ?

I have a Table A , that resides on Daatabase A on Workspace A

I want to create a fake table for Table A on Database B that resides on workspace B and then add a few extra columns. This will neeed the orginal data from Table A in it .

I know I can get the create statement of Table A from

> show create table Bi_db.TableA

Surely there is an easy way of doing this in Azure Data Bricks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, there is not yet a feature to do that directly on Databricks. However, we can generate DML scripts like INSERT for Databricks table by using SQL client application like DBeaver.  Consider my answer for another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72011789/11289386). It really works well for me.